# Get cursor position in ' ng2-ckeditor'

Tags: javascript, angular, ckeditor

I am new to angular 2 and using 'ng2-ckeditor 1.0.7' in angular 2 app.Editor is working goodin app. Now I want to append text at cursor position. But unable to find cursor position using angular2. I found the code using javascript, but I don't know how to do with angular2 / typescript.

My **editor.component.ts** file is -

```
@Component({
    selector: 'editor',
    template:'
      <ckeditor [(ngModel)]="ckEditorContent" [config]="ckEditorConfig"></ckeditor>

})

export class EditorComponent implements OnChanges {
    @Input() panelData: string;
    constructor() {
        this.ckEditorContent = '';
}

ckEditorContent: string;
ckEditorConfig: {} = { "uiColor": "#CFD8D3", "removeButtons": "Save,Templates,Find,Replace,Scayt,SelectAll,Smiley,Flash,SetLanguage" };

ngOnChanges(): void {

    this.ckEditorContent += this.panelData;
    console.log("this.panelData = " + this.panelData);
    console.log("this.ckEditorContent = " + this.ckEditorContent);
}

}
```

`

Answer (score 1):

In html file you implemeted ckeditor tag to implement.

```
<ckeditor [(ngModel)]="emailWidgetTemplate.content" id="email" [readonly]="false" 
     name="content" [config]="editorConfig" (contentDom)="onContentDom($event)"></ckeditor>
```

Something like this. In this I have implemeted method contentDom and implemented it in ts file.

```
onContentDom(e: any) {
        console.log('try e:', e);
        this.ckeditor = e.editor;
    }
```

Assigned editor object to some local variable ckeditor.

On button click you can use this editor variable in any method.

```
addText(someText){
  this.ckeditor.insertHtml(someText);
}
```

and it will add text at current cursor position.